# Partial sums and Fourier series approach

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to plot the partial sums for $N=5,10,15,20$ of the Fourier series of $f(x)=(1-x^2)^2$ and $-1<x<1.$ I have:

```
f[x_] = If[1 > x > -1, (1-x^2)^2];
L = 2;
a[n_] := (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
a[0] = (1/L)*Integrate[f[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
b[n_] := (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
F[x_, N_] := 
a[0] + Sum[a[n]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L] + b[n]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, N}]
Table[F[x, N], {N, 5, 20, 5}]
p[N_, a_] := 
Plot[Evaluate[F[x, N]], {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotPoints -> 200]
a[n]
a[0]
b[n]
Table[p[N, 1], {N, 5, 20, 5}]
g[x_, N_] := Abs[f[x] - F[x, N]]
Table[g[x, 7], {x, -1, 1, 2/10}]
```

Something is getting wrong. What should I do? Then, how could I use FourierTrigSeries, FourierParameters and FourierCoefficient?

Comment: what's the definition of a in the plotRange attribute?

Comment: $a=1$ ($1>x>-1$)

Comment: ah yes, i didn't realize it.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: i was trying but it doesn't work

Comment: Just a guess. `N` is a built-in symbol name, try using a different name.

Comment: `fun = Table[ (FourierSinSeries[
      Piecewise[{{(1 - t^2)^2, -1 < t < 1}} ], t, i] + 
     FourierCosSeries[Piecewise[{{(1 - t^2)^2, -1 < t < 1}} ], t, 
      i]), {i, 5, 15, 5}];
Plot[fun, {t, -1, 1}]`  is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you. And: g[x_, N_] := Abs[f[x] - F[x, N]]
Table[g[x, 7], {x, -1, 1, 2/10}]

Comment: @Alucard, what about the two last lines?

Comment: @George sorry for the delay , check my answer i think i made a mistake in the previous comment with `Piecewise`

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[g];
ClearAll[uff];
uff[a_, b_] := (FourierSinSeries[(1 - t^2)^2, t, b] + 
    FourierCosSeries[(1 - t^2)^2, t, b] ) /. t -> a
fun = Table[uff[a, i] , {i, 5, 15, 5}];
Plot[fun, {a, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
g[ x_ /; -1 <= x <= 1, n_] := Abs[(1 - x^2)^2 - uff[x, n]]
ListPlot[Table[N@g[x, 5], {x, -1, 1, 2/10}] ]
```

[image]